# MVVM OnPropertyChanged not changing view when using assignment operator (PropertyChanged becomes null)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to create an undo/redo system. Currently, when the user does something the original object and the new object are copied in a list per "action". If I press the undo button I want to assign the original value to the new value again.

I've been able to get both the new and the original object in the list but it goes wrong when assigning the old object again by using the undo I made. It gets updated in the main list that holds all the objects that can be changed but it isn't updating in the view.

This is how do the undo method:

```
for (int t = 0; t < mainData.GroupModelList.Count; ++t)
{
    if (mainData.GroupModelList[t].Name == commandList.ElementAt(position).groupModelNew.Name)
    {
        mainData.GroupModelList[t] = new ViewModels.GroupViewModel(commandList.ElementAt(position).groupModelOrig);
        break;
    }
}
```

This calls the constructor of the GroupViewModel:

```
public GroupViewModel(GroupViewModel selectedGroup)
{ 
    groupModel = new GroupModel();

    // values are assigned from the selectedGroup here (which is the original object in the UndoRedo part)
    // ...

    OnPropertyChanged(null);
 }
```

This is the OnPropertyChanged method:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
    }
}
```

I've read somewhere that using "null" at `PropertyChangedEventArgs` makes everything update, so that's what I tried but it isn't working.
After some more breakpoints I noticed that `PropertyChanged` is null when the new constructor is called, which is probably the problem. It does work without the Undo/Redo though. (When simply changing values the object holds using a textbox or similar)

I've also read that I should point the DataContext to the object itself but that doesn't seem to be possible since the object doesn't have a DataContext property.

EDIT: people have told me I should use ObservableCollection. I am already using that though. Like this: (This is the list the View has access to)

```
private ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> groupModelList = new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> GroupModelList
{
    get { return groupModelList; }
}
```

EDIT: This is how the binding is done to the View:
First of all here's the binding in XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
```

`MainViewModel` holds an object of type `MainData` and inside that class there's an `ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>`.
For example, this is the code that binds the name of the selected item from the list to a textbox in the View: (First line is the ListBox that shows all items in the GroupViewModel list, second one is the TextBox I want to give as an example)

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" Height="412" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=mainData.FilteredGroupModelList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,44,0,0" Name="lbFoundItems" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=SelectedGroup, Mode=OneWayToSource}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" SelectionMode="Single" />

<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lbFoundItems, Path=SelectedItem.Types, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="436,378,0,0" Name="cmbTypes" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=SelectedType, Mode=OneWayToSource}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
```

Also this is the `SelectedGroup` variable that holds a reference to the selected item in the ListBox:

```
private GroupViewModel selectedGroup;
public GroupViewModel SelectedGroup
{
    get { return selectedGroup; }
    set
    {
        selectedGroup = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGroup");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign the new instance of GroupViewModel? The object/viewmodel that is holding that instance needs to call the PropertyChangedEvent

Comment: In the first piece of code you can see that I assign the old object to the new one again. I search through the main list of objects and then assign it with `new`. Like so: `mainData.GroupModelList[t] = new ViewModels.GroupViewModel(commandList.ElementAt(position).groupModelOrig);`. Also, as you can see in the second piece of code the PropertyChanged is called in the constructor of the viewModel

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are changing the `DataContext` of the item in the list control by creating a new object with this line of code...

```
mainData.GroupModelList[t] = new ViewModels.GroupViewModel(commandList.ElementAt(position).groupModelOrig);
```

The `ItemsControl` that is bound to `mainData.GroupModelList` needs to be notified that the collection has changed, not that the individual `ViewModel` object has been updated.

Make sure that `GroupModelList` is an `ObservableCollection<T>` as it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

**Edit: "Do you have any references to how I should be doing it?"**

It's called the Memento pattern. Combine it with a Stack for full application undo/redo functionality. [Memento Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/memento-pattern.html)

Comment: Any help on how to do that?

Comment: I am using that already, I'll add this to my original question

Comment: How have you defined the `Binding` to `GroupModelList`? Could you post that as well?

Comment: I edited my question with that (I assume that is what you wanted to see)

Comment: Could you also post the definition of `SelectedGroup`? You don't appear to be using it anywhere in the undo code but have bound it to the `TextBox` for manipulating the `Name` property locally in the `TextBox` (you need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to update btw as `TextBox` by default uses `LostFocus`). If you're not creating a copy object when doing the assignment via the `OneWayToSource` `Binding` then you are actually just attempting to overwrite the original object's values and you have no original copy object saved anywhere.

Comment: I added it to the question. I might've given a bad example, I'm changing the textbox to the one I'm having difficulty with (I didn't add the undo/redo to the regular textboxes since you can use ctrl+z in those). Sorry! The control that doesn't update (the ComboBox) has the `UpdateSourcetrigger` set to `PropertyChanged` though.

Comment: Still the same comment - you're not creating a copy of your original object anywhere before editing it and are simply overwriting the properties of the selected object. Which means your "undo" code is nothing more than a copy constructor - the View doesn't change because none of the values have changed.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I thought I was doing it right since the data in the MainData list was updating as I want it to. Do you have any reference to how I should be doing it?

Answer (score 0):

What is 'everything' that is supposed to be updated here? Think about it for a second, there's no magic: UI elements bound to an instance of object are subscribed to `PropertyChanged`, that's why they get updated when it fires.

**UPD:**
I  don't think I can get a full picture here, it's not clear what are you trying to update and what classes are you using. Your example contains `for`, `if` and `break`, but no XAML! Is this really important when discussing WPF mechanics?.. How can I be sure the bug is not there? **Decompose the task.** Decompose it with no remorse. Create a small proj, get a collection on items and play with just wpf, regardless of your business. When you will do this, 70% chance you will find the root cause by yourself, 20% to google successfully, and asking the question will help you with the rest 10% of cases.

Comment: I am using `ObservableCollection` for the GroupModelList.

Answer (score 0):

try RaisePropertyChanged(); it requires no parameters when used from within the peoperty setter